# How to move files with specific extension from subdirectories to another directory including creating the subdirectories the files are from using CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Directory **`C:\Parent`** contains two subdirectories.

```
\basis             //contains folders which contain .pdf and .txt files
\basis_ft          //empty
```

I'd like to move all **`*.txt`** files from **`\basis`** to **`\basis_ft`** but they need to be in the exact same subdirectory they've been in before.

- Before:

```
C:\Parent\basis\UD00\
 00000A00.pdf
 00000A0A.pdf
 ft00000A00.txt
 ft00000A0A.txt
C:\Parent\basis_ft\   //empty
```

- After:

```
C:\Parent\basis\UD00\
 00000A00.pdf
 00000A0A.pdf
C:\Parent\basis_ft\UD00\
 ft00000A00.txt
 ft00000A0A.txt
```

There are a lot of subdirectories like **`UD00`** which include different numbers of files.

My current statement is as follows:

```
for /r "C:\Parent\basis\" %%x in (*.txt) do move "%%x" "C:\Parent\basis_ft"
```

But this only gets all **`*.txt`** files out and into the folder **`basis_ft`**.

Any of you guys have an idea on how to do this?

I'd like to add that I'd prefer to do this in one statement without creating a text file first that list all the required content and another file the uses this file to create the directories an moving the files the after. And in the end, there is still a text file to delete. I've done it like this is the past but I'm eager to simplify this process, because I'm going to need to do this more often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that ROBOCOPY will do what you want. Learn about the options using `ROBOCOPY /?`.

```
ROBOCOPY /S /MOV C:\Parent\basis C:\Parent\basis_ft *.txt
```

If you are ready to use PowerShell, you could do the following. When you are sure that the correct files will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` command.

```
Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Parent\basis' -Destination 'C:\Parent\basis_ft' `
    -Filter '*.txt' -Recurse
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Parent\basis' -Filter '*.txt' |
    ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf }
```

Comment: Thank you for both methods. The ROBOCOPY work fine but the PowerShell script creates a `basis` folder under `basis_ft` and I can't seem to figure out why. Even though I have a solution now, I'd very much like to know why the PowerShell script works as it does.

Comment: @Draco - The PowerShell commands work on my machine running `($PSVersionTable.PSVersion).ToString() => 5.1.18362.628`. Are you sure that the directory was not there from an earlier attempt? Also, I corrected the directory path in the second command.

Comment: I've tried it several more times. `basis_ft` is empty. The PowerShell script creates the folder `basis`. I've copied your script and did not change anything. I'm running the same version as you.

Answer (score 0):

This directory creation and file movement task could be done with:

```
@echo off
set "BaseFolder=C:\Parent\basis"
for /D %%I in ("%BaseFolder%\*") do if exist "%%I\*.txt" (
    if not exist "%BaseFolder%_ft\%%~nxI\" md "%BaseFolder%_ft\%%~nxI" 2>nul
    if exist "%BaseFolder%_ft\%%~nxI\" move /Y "%%I\*.txt" "%BaseFolder%_ft\%%~nxI\" >nul
)
set "BaseFolder="
```

This batch script searches for non-hidden subfolders in specified base folder and assigns each full qualified folder name to loop variable `I` one after the other.

For each subfolder in base folder it is checked if there is at least one file with file extension `.txt`.

If that condition is true, it is checked next if there is the appropriate target folder which is a subfolder with same name as the current subfolder in base folder in the target base folder with `_ft` appended to base folder name. The target folder is created if not already existing.

Next is checked if the target folder now really exists, i.e. the target folder creation was really successful. If that is the case, all files with file extension `.txt` are moved from current subfolder in base folder to appropriate target subfolder in base target folder with overwriting perhaps already existing text files with same file name.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `>nul`.